# Change image on selection in UITableViewCell(swift 3 xcode)

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have an imageView inside my tableViewCell and i would like to have its image changed on selection. This is the code I have for it:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableCell
    myCell.resourceIcons.image = UIImage(named: "RubiusResources2")
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

The code works, but some of the other rows in a different section further down the tableView also seem change.

EDIT:

Using the comments bellow I came to the following solution:

I first created a 2D bool array to the amount of sections and rows my table had and set them all to false.

```
var resourceBool = Array(repeating: Array(repeating:false, count:4), count:12)
```

I then created an if statement to check if the array at indexPath was false or true. This would be where the states of the image would change.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let myCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellId", for: indexPath) as! TableCell

    if (global.resourceBool[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == false) {
        myCell.resourceIcons.image = global.systemResourceImages[0]
    } else if (global.resourceBool[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] == true) {
        myCell.resourceIcons.image = global.systemResourceImages[1]
    }

    return myCell
}
```

Then, in the didSelectRow function I change the array at indexPath to true and reload the tableView data.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    global.resourceBool[indexPath.section][indexPath.row] = true
    tableView.reloadData()
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

}
```

From my understanding, the states of an object must always be in the cellForRow.

Comment: See my comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44618366/swift-uicollectionview-cells-arent-staying-in-order#comment76222954_44618366 it is the same thing for tableviews, cells are getting reused, cells must not hold state, your image change is state.

Comment: There is a cell reuse. You need to set always the original background on prepareForReuse from cell. Basically, on prepareForReuse, you should set all the properties from cell as original state.

Comment: @luk2302 is right that's a good solution, but there is one more solution for you problem, if you are using same image for selected state for all cell then put that image in imageView's highlighted state and change the state for the selected row row only.
and use you normal image in .image property.

Comment: So my image change is a state and my cell cannot hold one. How do I then get the desired effect? How do I have an image in my cell change on selection?

Comment: @teixeiras I placed the original state within prepareForReuse and it seemed to work. However, now when I scroll past the changed image it will revert back to the original state. How do i get the image to stay in the new state?

Comment: you need to always set the image on  cellForRowAtIndexPath whenever

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solution would be that you need to maintain a seperate list of rows you selected, compare them in `cellForRowAt` method.

Code would look something like this.

```
var selectedArray : [IndexPath] = [IndexPath]()

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let myCell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TableCell
    myCell.resourceIcons.image = UIImage(named: "RubiusResources2")
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

    if(!selectedArray.contains(indexPath))
    {
        selectedArray.append(indexPath)
    }
    else
    {
        // remove from array here if required
    }
}
```

and then in `cellForRowAt`, write this code to set proper images

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        .
        .
        .

        if(selectedArray.contains(indexPath))
        {
            // use selected image
        }
        else
        {
            // use normal image
        }

        .
        .
        .
    }
```